# Order form for materials on donation basis (CiviCRM / WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, donations, caldera-forms

We are new to CiviCRM and are looking for an **easy way** to enable the following:

*Must have:*

- An interested person may order materials (e.g. postcards) and may promise to give donations for it
- Verification email
- The person and a person doing the shipping should receive an email

*Nice to have:*

1. Update of CiviCRM contact
2. Creating a activity for that contact
3. Possibility to do the donation with CiviCRM

From StackExchange research I got the impression that best way to do the "must haves" and 1./2. would be a best to use Caldera Forms + Caldera CiviCRM Plugin + Caldera Verify Form.

Is this the appropriate way to do it, or is there something easier (e.g. CiviCRM forms/profiles)?

Is it possible to include the donation from CiviCRM directly into such a thing? (It's not a shop function, where you have to pay, it should really be a donation.)

Answer (score 2):

In theory you can set up a Contribution page with Price Set with all your 'merchandise' available as Price Fields so they could order eg 5 postcards or 3 x pack of 3 cards etc.

Then i you set the form for Pay Later that becomes a 'promise' which is recorded in civicrm as a pending transaction.

when they submit then the purchaser will get an email, and the 'person doing the shipping' can be added as a CC or BCC via the Contribution Page settings

may not fit what you need but worth understanding what is possible via that route

it does not create the Activity (other than the one that CiviCRM creates for any contribution)